Maple Leaf Rag to Prelude in G Minor
I just got done learning the entirety of Maple Leaf Rag, now I'm interested in learning Rachmaninoff's Prelude in G Minor Op. 23 No 5. I'm wondering, is it too big of a jump to go from Maple Leaf to Prelude in G Minor? (I have a piano teacher) I can reach a 10th, but might clash with some other notes if I don't play at the edges of the keys. I also learn pretty fast, anyway, if you have any tips that'd be great. :)

Welcome to the site.  You say that you have a teacher.  Have you asked them?  What is their view?

My teacher basically lets me choose to learn whatever I want to learn, I haven't really been told more than that it's a very difficult piece.

There are many reasons to have lessons with a teacher, but one of them is that they can help pick pieces that are “just a bit“ harder than your current level so you can always progress without facing impossible challenges. Consider asking them directly, or maybe consider finding another teacher. At any rate, the only harm in trying a piece that’s too hard is getting frustrated and having to stop for now

It's a big jump. But give it a try! You shouldn't find the first section completely impossible.

As long as it doesn’t ruin your motivation by being frustrating there is nothing wrong with trying something hard. Even if you cannot do certain things in tempo you can still learn quite a lot from doing this. So if you want to try it, just try it. If it is totally too much you will notice, and if it is not you might not get anywhere near 100% there, but that is fine I believe when learning an instrument. Some pieces might accompany you for a long time. And evertime you try to play it, you’ll see how much progress you made in between.

Adding to what Andy wrote above, a (good) teacher is also able to know the "hidden" difficulties in a piece. Being able to reach a 10th is only one of the many aspects and challenges that must be addressed when facing a new piece, especially if you're a beginner (even relatively speaking). Consider some metaphors: does being more than 6ft tall and knowing how to play basketball suffice to make you a fully qualified NBA candidate? Would it be enough to own and drive a 200 MPH car to make you a Formula One driver? This doesn't mean that you shouldn't try and learn, it would certainly be an »

» effective way to know about many aspects (and your current limits, and I'm not just talking about physical ones), so nobody tells you shouldn't even try to begin with. But, you got a teacher: talk to them, ask about the challenges it would present, both for any fully trained pianist and for your current capabilities. But also try to consider the "hidden" difficulties mentioned above, as it's common in early learning stages to overestimate our own capabilities, like "I learn pretty fast": which may be true, but you'll probably soon find out that it's not "as fast" as you initially thought.
